# AVAssetWriter: Momentary Lag When Starting Write

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am developing an app that records a video using AVAssetWriter (the source media are sample buffers output from `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`.

I've noticed that the very first time I instantiate my `AVAssetWriter`, then call `startWriting()` and `startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime)`, there is a lag of about 30ms.  This causes the video preview on the screen to momentarily hang, which also results in the first few frames of the video not write properly.

Curiously, if I then re-instantiate my `AVAssetWriter` and take all of the same steps again, everything works fine from that point onward.  This only occurs the very first time.

While perhaps too lengthy to post, this is the function in which I am certain the error is occurring;

```
func insert(pixel buffer: CVPixelBuffer, with time: CMTime) {

    // Check for unknown status
    if fileWriter.status == .unknown {
        guard startingVideoTime == nil else {
            print("We've received an error setting the starting video time.")
            return
        }
        startingVideoTime = time
        if fileWriter.startWriting() {
            fileWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startingVideoTime!)
            isRecording = true
        }
    }

    // Append buffer
    if videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        append(pixel: buffer, with: time)
        isRecording = true
    }
}
```

For posterity, I am calling the above function from my `captureOutput`, only doing so when my `self.isRecording = true`, which I set when the user taps a "Start Record" button.

Comment: Did you solve this? Actually I am facing same problem.. Thanks for reply

Comment: @bezoadam Not yet.  Still can't figure it out.  I can tell I'm dropping a frame when the AVAssetWriter is instantiated, which is probably what's producing the visible "lag," but still have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

```
let videoCompressionSettings: [String: Any] = [
  AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
  AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(value: 1080),
  AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(value: 1920)
]
let audioCompressionSettings: [String: Any] = [
  AVNumberOfChannelsKey: NSNumber(value: 1),
  AVEncoderAudioQualityForVBRKey: NSNumber(value: 91),
  AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey:NSNumber(value: 9600),
  AVEncoderBitRateStrategyKey: AVAudioBitRateStrategy_Variable,
  AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(value: 1633772320),
  AVSampleRateKey: NSNumber(value: 44100)
]
// My own wrapper for AVAssetWriter
movieWriterManager = MovieWriterManager(videoUrl: recordingVideoURL(), audioUrl: recordingAudioURL(), videoCompressionSettings: videoCompressionSettings, audioCompressionSettings: audioCompressionSettings)
movieWriterManager?.warmup()
```

You may try to buy time by running the same steps at AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with a default videoCompressionSettings and audioCompressionSettings. It's actually not blocking UI thread but only the video output connection of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.